# javascript variables to ajax for realtime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, real-time

I am fetching values from database using php and what to show it in realtime as those values are changing every second and I want to display it in real time.

This is my PHP code.

```
$sql = 'select * from cpu_usage where id=(select max(id) from cpu_usage)';
$login ='select count(*) as count from audit_trail';
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    $CPU=$row['CPU'];
    $MEM=$row['MEM'];
}
foreach ($dbh->query($login) as $row)
{
$active=$row['count'];
}
```

I want to show values of `$CPU`, `$MEM` and `$active` in real time. I don't have any knowledge in JavaScript or AJAX.

Comment: *"I don't have any knowledge in javascript or ajax"* That's an easy problem to solve: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started . Aside from that, do you actually have a question?

Comment: @both: JakeGould: The only problem is I am in my company's hackathon and need this in 3 hours, anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @Himanshu: Then I would start learning JS immediately or ask a co-worker to help you. This is not rent-a-coder where you can hire someone to implement a complete feature for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it.

the jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function poll_results(){
    $.get('/path/to/your/file.php', function(result){
        $('body').html('CPU: '+result.cpu+', MEM: '+result.mem+', ACTIVE: '+result.active);
        setTimeout(poll_results, 1000);
    }, 'json');
}
$(function(){
    poll_results();
});
</script>
```

The php:

```
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    $ret['cpu'] = $row['CPU'];
    $ret['mem'] = $row['MEM'];
}
foreach ($dbh->query($login) as $row)
{
    $ret['active'] = $row['count'];
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```